# Integer solution to $19x^3-84y^2=1984$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Show that there exist no integer values $x,y$ such that $19x^3-84y^2=1984$.

Please help me in understanding no solution problems.

I tried to check the modulo $7$ of both sides but couldn't reject some cases.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: you should try $19$ instead of $7$.

Comment: At the moment you can tell that $x$ must be even, because the coefficients are not pairwise coprime. You can therefore reduce - here set $x=4t, y=4u$ and cancel a factor of $64$ to get the equivalent equation $19t^3-21u^2=31$

Comment: @MarkBennet, how do you get from $x$ even to $x=4t$?  Are you skipping a couple of steps?

Comment: @BarryCipra - morally, yes - set $x=2q$ to start etc is the by hand method. However looking at the powers of two which divide the coefficients you get $0,2,6$. You want the maximum $a,b$ with $0+3a\le 6$ and $2+2b\le 6$ whence $a=b=2$ and you use $x=2^at, y=2^bu$

Comment: @MarkBennet, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

Working modulo 7,

$$
19x^3 − 84y^2 \equiv 1984 \\
5x^3 \equiv 3 \\
15x^3 \equiv 9 \\
x^3 \equiv 2 \\
$$

By inspection, $x^3 \equiv 2 \mod 7 \,$ has no solutions:

$$
\begin{array}{c|r|c} 
x & x^3 & x^3\mod 7 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 8 & 1 \\
3 & 27 & 6 \\
4 & 64 & 1 \\
5 & 125 & 6 \\
6 & 216 & 6 \\
\end{array}
$$

Or we could invoke [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and note that for all $x: x\mod 7 \neq 0,\, x^6 = 1$, hence $x^3 = \pm 1 \mod 7$

---

Alternatively, working mod 19

$$
19x^3 − 84y^2 \equiv 1984 \\
 − 8y^2 \equiv 8 \\
$$

Note that $7 \times 8 = 56 \equiv -1 \mod 19$

So

$$y^2 \equiv -1 \mod 19$$

But according to the [the first supplement to the law of quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement)

$$y^2 \equiv -1 \mod p$$ for prime $p$ only has solutions if $p  \equiv 1 \mod 4 $ . And since $19 \mod 4 \equiv 3\,$ there are no solutions for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as $19(x^3-100)$$=84(1+y^2)$. Now check the remainders when divided by $7$. The RHS gives $0$, so LHS should also be a multiple of $7$. This implies  $$ 7 \mid (x^3-100)$$$$\implies 7 \mid (x^3-2)$$ and Voila! No cube of a natural number gives remainder $2$ when divided by $7$. Proof: I know a rigorous and tedious one. If somebody knows a shorter one, please enlighten me. Consider the number to be of the form $7k+n$, where $k=0,1\cdots$ and $n \in [0,6]$. Do the cube and you just need to find the remainder when $n^3$ is divided by $7$. I think it is pretty clear from here .And thus, it completes the proof that no integral solutions exist.

Comment: How do you show that $x^3 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 7, \forall x$?

Comment: Note that $x^6\equiv 1 \bmod 7$ for $x$ not a multiple of $7$. So $x^3\equiv\pm\sqrt 1$ - and since $7$ is prime, there are only two square roots, namely $\pm 1$.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Believe it or not, I added the Fermat's little theorem info to my answer before I read your comment. :) I originally didn't include it because I didn't know if the OP has covered that material yet, but decided to add it for completeness.

Comment: Thanks to all of you but sorry you were late I had solved the question. Pls try trigo bash

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ 3\equiv -2x^3\,\overset{\rm square}\Rightarrow\, 3^2\equiv 4x^6\overset{\rm Fermat}\equiv 4\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$